# Automated way to backup Google account data to local PC

Tags: google-apps

I want an automated way to backup the important (to me) parts of my Google account automatically. I want to backup to a local PC, in some reasonable file format (I already have backups of the local PC.

The things I want to backup are:

- Email (optional)
- Contacts
- Calendar Items
- Chrome bookmarks
- Drive contents (optional)
- Google+ posts and circles (optional)

Things I have already automated piecemeal, but might be nice to have as part of an all-in-one:

- E-mail via the tool '[Got Your Back](https://github.com/jay0lee/got-your-back)'
- Drive contents (I sync my Drive to a local machine and back it up).

Tools I know of that don't really solve the problem:

- Google export - the export functions are manually initiated. I need automation.
- spinbackup.com - I have no idea who these guys are, but a backup to yet another cloud service just seems like a bad idea to me, setting aside the questions of privacy and security.

I'm willing to pay a little bit of money for software, though of course, free is always good.

Linux or Windows is fine, I can arrange any necessary environment for the tool to run in.